# "CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT" problem in CLion under Windows 10

Tags: c++, cmake, cygwin, clion, jetbrains-ide

I want to install C++ in CLion on Windows 10, but the software emerges such problem named:

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in

CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.


Error code: 1
```

I don't know why and this is my brief screenshot of CLion:

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried the method mentioned in other post but they are under Linux environment which is different to my Windows 10.

Comment: Unrelated to the error you're getting, you need to install the `make` program and a C and C++ compiler in the Cygwin environment.

Comment: As for the error you're asking about, how *did* you install CLion? And what "other post" are you referring to? How did you create your project?

Comment: Maybe the problem is caused by a space in the path?

Comment: ***you need to install the make program and a C and C++ compiler in the Cygwin environment*** Doesn't cygwin install the compiler by default? I have not used it in years so I could be very wrong.

Comment: @drescherjm I haven't used Cygwin in quite some time either, but I don't think it comes by default (memory is hazy though). Which makes it weirder that the debugger *is* installed.